# Jest enzyme mock function not working with toHaveBeenCalled and mock.calls.length

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am learning react unit testing, I wrote simple test case but its not working, I googled a lot and everywhere I see same example and that's not working for me. I tried both ways toHaveBeenCalled/mock.calls.length.

Counter is getting increased, I know i can check/test counter value to find out if button is clicked, But what If there isn't any counter and I just want to make sure that button click triggers a function ?

I know if i move this function to some other file and then import it then below test will pas since I am passing that function as prop. But what if i want to test a function which is not imported and in the same file ?

[Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-dhawan-d6vvl)

```
import React from "react";
import "./Login.css";

class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  doLogin = (event) => {
    let { counter } = this.state;
    this.setState((prevstate) => ({ counter: prevstate.counter + 1 }));
    // console.log("Handle login button click");
  };

  render() {
    const { counter } = this.state;
    return (
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellPadding={4}>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button onClick={this.doLogin}>LogIn</button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;{counter}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Test case

```
it("Handle login button click", () => {
  const mockOnClick = jest.fn();

  const wrapper = shallow(<Login onClick={mockOnClick} />);
  wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
  wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
  // mockOnClick();
  console.log(wrapper.state("counter"));
  // expect(mockOnClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mockOnClick.mock.calls.length).toEqual(2);
});
```

Comment: Rather than posting a link to a full application demo in sandbox, can you please paste the relevant code and tests into your comment?

Comment: Okay, Just a min. Normally people prefer demo so I did that, But let me post both.

Comment: @petarkolaric : Done!

Comment: the problem here is that the `Login` component doesn't have an `onClick` event, the button inside does.  you're not actually binding to the correct element, and therefore never actually calling your mock function.

Comment: @Claies : Okay got it now, Above test case will work if I pass that function as prop or import that function from other file. I also found way to test class functions https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1432 But again this page show how to test protype functions but what if I want to test arrow function like I am using.

Comment: if the mock were firing, the counter ***would not be increasing***, because the mock is fired **instead of** the actual function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `onClick` event is on the `button` rather than on the `Login` component, the function isn't bound the way you expect.  What you actually have to do is mock the component, then *replace* the function with the faked function.

```js
it("Handle login button click", () => {
  const mockOnClick = jest.fn();

  const wrapper = shallow( < Login / > );
  wrapper.instance().doLogin = mockOnClick;
  //MUST forceUpdate or the first .simulate call will trigger the real function.
  wrapper.instance().forceUpdate();  
  wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
  wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
  // mockOnClick();
  console.log(wrapper.state("counter"));
  // expect(mockOnClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mockOnClick.mock.calls.length).toEqual(2);
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-easley-hd0hc

Note that the `instance` must be `forceUpdate` to avoid the real function being called.  Also, this is replacing the function with a fake function instead of calling the real function, and is thus just testing the `onClick` mechanism itself, which isn't really a useful test of app functionality.

Comment: Thanks! "which isn't really a useful test of app functionality", Do you mean I should also test/validate the reaction caused by that function instead of just testing if it gets called ? Like if that function is firing some axios req then I should also test it with moxios, Or if its changing the state then I should test state variable for changes ? Like `expect(wrapper.state("counter")).toEqual(2)`

Comment: correct.  you always want to be testing the *results* of your components rather than the *activation* of them whenever possible.